# Style copy/paste options in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How do I style the copy/paste options panel in flutter? As you can see it's overflowing and not looking good also.

[image]

Edit: I was able to change the color by setting canvasColor in theme data but how do I solve the overflow issue.